# How to turn rows into columns grouped?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe:

```
 id1     id2    val   type
"a1"    "a2"     10    "a"
"a1"    "b2"     11    "b"
"a1"    "c2"     9     "c"
"k1"    "p2"     6     "a"
"k1"    "f2"     5     "b"
"k1"    "d2"     2     "c"
```

i want for each unique id1 put each id2 on same row with val and type. so desired result is:

```
 id1     id2_a  val_a    id2_b  val_b   id2_c   val_c  
"a1"     "a2"     10     "b2"    11      "c2"     9
"k1"     "p2"     6      "f2"     5      "d2"     2
```

how could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
# pivot 
df2=df.pivot(index=['id1'], columns='type')

# sort on second level, to obtained the intended sequence
df2=df2.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)

# merge column index level, while stripping off the quotes
df2.columns=[col[0]+"_"+col[1].lstrip('""').rstrip('""') for col in df2]

# remove the axis name
df2=df2.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()

# result
df2
```

```
    id1     id2_a   val_a   id2_b   val_b   id2_c   val_c
0   "a1"    "a2"    10      "b2"    11      "c2"    9
1   "k1"    "p2"    6       "f2"    5       "d2"    2
```